# 4 level hierarchical Pandas DataFrame of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a four dimensional hierarchically indexed Pandas dataframe. I found the documentation for multi-indexing

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
           np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=arrays)
```

Instead of this I want four arrays for my indices and I want them of different lengths. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Post *exactly* what you want with a reproducible example ([mcve]). This can be done in many ways *including* the way you just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a matter of how you represent your data.
In essence, this is not a Series, it is a DataFrame with 5 columns:

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"level_0":{"0":"bar","1":"bar","2":"baz","3":"baz","4":"foo","5":"foo","6":"qux","7":"qux"},"level_1":{"0":"one","1":"two","2":"one","3":"two","4":"one","5":"two","6":"one","7":"two"},"level_2":{"0":"a","1":"b","2":"c","3":"d","4":"e","5":"f","6":"g","7":"h"},"level_3":{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8"},"0":{"0":1.7686082254,"1":-1.2237523116,"2":-1.3066335651,"3":-1.3800965009,"4":-0.5995811728,"5":-1.4717242393,"6":-1.0613097567,"7":-0.3232780637}})
```

You get:

[image]

and then you can set the index as a 4 level index

```
df = df.set_index(['level_0', 'level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3'])
```

and your get your 4 level indexed Series

[image]

The original DataFrame could be missing values (i.e. your index array would originally be 'of different length') and that gives you what you are looking for.